# Mysqli count returning incorrect number

Tags: php, mysqli

so i have this

```
$countsql = <<<SQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `deathnote`
SQL;

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $countsql)) {
/* execute query */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
/* store result */
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt));
}
```

The output of this is 1.
Now, when i go into PHP admin on my server and run the exact same query i receive the expected outcome of 12.

Can anybody see where i went wrong, or suggest what to do?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Why use a prepared statement for this? Just use `mysqli->query()`

Comment: It should be pretty much a common sense. If you rund `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` in your mysql (let's say console, client, whatever) how many rows do you recieve? Only ONE telling you COUNT(*) = smth. So, yes, this query returns only ONE row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` OR use `COUNT(*)` don't mix both.

With `mysqli_stmt_num_rows` Query should be

```
SELECT *
FROM `deathnote`;
```

**OR**

With `COUNT(*)` *Recommend to use this way for better performance and fast execution of code*

```
$res = mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deathnote");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: For the question given, Query should be COUNT(*).

Comment: @YourCommonSense concept is number of rows

Comment: Concept always is running sane queries that won't kill your server.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Helped me immensely.

Comment: As @YourCommonSense stated, in case you only need the number of rows and not the values of the rows, performance would improve by using `COUNT(*)`. But in that case, don't use the `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`-function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deathnote");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)
echo "Number of rows: $row[0]\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the value of COUNT(*), not the number of rows -- the number of rows will always be one: a single row, with one column, containing the value of COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0):

you are taking sql count function very wrong here basically its an aggregate function which returns only 1 as you used printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt)); if you want your desired result which you say is 12 then you will can use mysqli_result, mysqli_fetch_array i-e